# LAN static lease for Hyper-V VMs

Tags: networking, ip, virtual-machines, hyper-v, mac-address

I have a question about reserving IP addresses for VMs that run on my laptop.

In this case, my laptop serves as a switch.
But the thing is, how can I lease a VM an IP address in my LAN by MAC, as all of the VMs are sharing the same interface => the MAC is identical.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnDOh.png)

Answer (score 1):

> as all of the VMs are sharing the same interface => the MAC is identical

That is not how VM's work - the VM's will have all their own MAC address OR they can not be on the same ethernet segmet. Check your basics. If they "share" a MAC address, then someting must act as NAT device and then you will ahve your own in laptop dhcp server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 things on the same network with the same mac address. It'll break basic communications.

I'm too lazy to install Hyper-V on my PC and check but you will need to use a bridged adapter (VMWare term)